# Класс в заголовочном файле

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь впихнуть класс в заг. файл. Вот такой код:

Файл `__playerClass.h`:

```
////////////////////////
#ifndef __EV_PL_CLASS //
#define __EV_PL_CLASS //
////////////////////////
#include <windows.h>
#include <cmath>

#include <GL\glut.h>

#define PI 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117067982148086513282306647093845

#define EV_FORWARD_KEY 200
#define EV_LEFT_KEY    201
#define EV_BACK_KEY    202
#define EV_RIGHT_KEY   203
#define EV_UP_KEY      204
#define EV_DOWN_KEY    205

class EV_PLAYER {
public:
    float angleX = 0, angleY = 0;
    double x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, speed = 90, speed_op = 1,
        w = 1, h = 1, d = 1, h_eye = 1;

    EV_PLAYER();
    void mouse();
    void keyboard1(int key);
    void keyboard2(int key, bool free = true);
    void jump();
    void fps_reload(int fps);
    void apply();
}__pl;
/////////
#endif //
/////////
```

Файл `__playerClass.cpp`:

```
#include "__playerClass.h"

EV_PLAYER::EV_PLAYER() {
    ShowCursor(false);
}

void EV_PLAYER::mouse() {
    POINT EV_M_POS;
    GetCursorPos(&EV_M_POS);

    angleX += (600 - EV_M_POS.x) / 4;
    angleY += (500 - EV_M_POS.y) / 4;

    if (angleX > 359.99)
        angleX -= 360;
    else if (angleX < -359.99)
        angleX += 360;

    if (angleY < -89.99)
        angleY = -89.99;
    else if (angleY > 89.99)
        angleY = 89.99;

    SetCursorPos(600, 500);
}

void EV_PLAYER::keyboard1(int key) {
    if (key == EV_FORWARD_KEY) {
        x += -sin(angleX / 180 * PI) * speed_op;
        y += tan(angleY / 180 * PI) * speed_op;
        z += -cos(angleX / 180 * PI) * speed_op;
    }else if (key == EV_BACK_KEY) {
        x += sin(angleX / 180 * PI) * speed_op;
        y += -tan(angleY / 180 * PI) * speed_op;
        z += cos(angleX / 180 * PI) * speed_op;
    }

    if (key == EV_LEFT_KEY) {
        x += sin((angleX - 90) / 180 * PI) * speed_op;
        z += cos((angleX - 90) / 180 * PI) * speed_op;
    }else if (key == EV_RIGHT_KEY) {
        x += sin((angleX + 90) / 180 * PI) * speed_op;
        z += cos((angleX + 90) / 180 * PI) * speed_op;
    }

    if (key == EV_UP_KEY)
        y += speed_op;
    else if (key == EV_DOWN_KEY)
        y -= speed_op;
}

void EV_PLAYER::keyboard2(int key, bool free) {
    if (key == EV_FORWARD_KEY) {
        x -= sin(angleX / 180 * PI) * speed_op;
        z -= cos(angleX / 180 * PI) * speed_op;
    }else if (key == EV_BACK_KEY) {
        x += sin(angleX / 180 * PI) * speed_op;
        z += cos(angleX / 180 * PI) * speed_op;
    }

    if (key == EV_LEFT_KEY) {
        x += sin((angleX - 90) / 180 * PI) * speed_op;
        z += cos((angleX - 90) / 180 * PI) * speed_op;
    }else if (key == EV_RIGHT_KEY) {
        x += sin((angleX + 90) / 180 * PI) * speed_op;
        z += cos((angleX + 90) / 180 * PI) * speed_op;
    }

    if (key == EV_UP_KEY) {
        if (free)
            y += speed_op;
        else
            jump();
    }else if (key == EV_DOWN_KEY)
        if (free)
            y -= speed_op;
}

void EV_PLAYER::jump() {

}

void EV_PLAYER::fps_reload(int fps) {
    speed_op = speed / fps;
}

void EV_PLAYER::apply() {
    gluLookAt(x, y + h_eye, z, x - sin(angleX / 180 * PI), y + h_eye + (tan(angleY / 180 * PI)), z - cos(angleX / 180 * PI), 0, 1, 0);
}
```

Но, к сожалению компилятор ругается, хотя этот класс объявлен только здесь.

```
1>  main.cpp
1>  __playerClass.cpp
1>  Создание кода...
1>__playerClass.obj : error LNK2005: "class EV_PLAYER __pl" (?__pl@@3VEV_PLAYER@@A) уже определен в main.obj
1>C:\Users\Вамиг\Desktop\Программирование\Проекты\evoluRia\Debug\evoluRia.exe : fatal error LNK1169: обнаружен многократно определенный символ - один или более
========== Сборка: успешно: 0, с ошибками: 1, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 0 ==========
```

Comment: И да, кстати, как код форматировать? (чтобы он не был таким "жирным", как вверху)

Comment: Обращение к этому файлу в main.php: #include "__playerClass.h".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правильно ругается. Вы объявляете переменную `__pl` в заголовочном файле, и она появляется везде, где этот файл инклудится. То есть как минимум - в `__playerClass.cpp` и `main.cpp`. Просто уберите объявление переменной из `__playerClass.h` и создайтё её в `main.cpp`.